# Managing Autoscroll

Tags: c#, scroll, flowlayoutpanel

My Project is currently in C# Winforms.

I have a custom control that I am inserting on a flow layout panel.

I also have a header that fits above the Flow Layout.

I would like the flowlayout to scroll on the vertical axis while the whole panel scrolls along the horizontal axis.

The problem I am having is that the flowlayout when autoscroll is set to true makes use of both horizontal and vertical scroll

I need the header to scroll horizontally at the same time as the flowlayout but not show its own horizontal scrollbar. I also need the header to stay at the top of the Panel when the flowlayout scrolls vertically.

Thanks for the help

I have been trying out different combinations of autoscroll, wrapcontents and Autosize.

Comment: Create a panel and put into the panel two panels.  One for the header and one for the data.

Comment: You can put header in readonly textbox with horizontal scrolling enabled.